# Past perfect continuous for continuing events in the past

Tags: tense, usage, past-continuous

My Cambridge Dictionary's grammar section contains the following explanation about the past perfect continuous tense:

> **Continuing events in the past**

> We use the past perfect continuous to talk about actions or events which started before a particular time in the past and were still in progress up to that time in the past:

Are these examples good?

1. I had been running when (=suddenly) I saw an exotic bird!
2. I had been working on my project when (=suddenly) a virus destroyed it!

In example 1, if I visualize that moment... I am running and in a moment something happens (an exotic bird flying near me which makes me observe it for a moment, until it disappears...); then I continue running.

My question is: **Did I use past perfect continuous correctly in those examples?**